# AngularJS undefined function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, cordova, scope

I have two angularJS $scope functions inside a main one. When calling the play() function there is an error stating that getPhoneGapPath() is undefined. What is the solution to this

My Code:

```
function DontAsk($scope){
$scope.getPhoneGapPath = function(){

    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.substr( 0, path.length - 10 );
    return 'file://' + path;

}
$scope.play= function(){
    var os = navigator.platform;
    if (os=='iPhone'){
        var url = "sounds/DontEventAsk.mp3";
    }
    else{
        var url = getPhoneGapPath() + "sounds/DontEventAsk.mp3";
    }
    var my_media = new Media(url,
        // success callback
        function() {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        },
        // error callback
        function(err) {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: "+JSON.stringify(err));
    });

    // Play audio
    my_media.play();
}}
```

Ideally I would want the getPhoneGapPath() to be defined and also outside the main function because I have multiple functions like the DontAsk() one.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `getPhoneGapPath` function in the scope. You are defining this function as a property of the `$scope` object, so you should use it accordingly:

```
$scope.getPhoneGapPath()
```

Comment: It is not fair :( You are too fast ))

Comment: Ahh, great thanks so much. @nicael You're right he was very fast.

Answer (score 2):

```
var url = $scope.getPhoneGapPath() + "sounds/DontEventAsk.mp3";
```